# initialize, set, and Return Structure inline?

Tags: vb.net, initialization, return, structure, setvalue

In vb.net, is it possible to initialize, set, and `Return` a `Structure` inline?

If I have this `Structure`

```
Structure CopyAndPasteUniquesAndExistenceStructure
    Dim duplicatePoints As List(Of Array)
    Dim inexistentPoints As List(Of Array)
    Dim insertedRows As List(Of Object)
End Structure
```

How can I do this pseudo?

```
Return New CopyAndPasteUniquesAndExistenceStructure...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Return New CopyAndPasteUniquesAndExistenceStructure With {.duplicatePoints = New List(Of Array), .inexistentPoints = New List(Of Array), .insertedRows = New List(Of Object)}
```

Or you can add a specialized constructor. This is useful if you want to validate the input, or if you want to make the lists read-only (which usually makes a lot of sense for lists).